# Nativescript install on windows doesn't work.

Tags: nativescript

I installed nativescript from https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup page, and when I checked `tns doctor` I get this error:

[image]

I could search for the errors and probably learn a thing or two about the errors, but what I don't understand is why the installer itself didn't install Android SDK 22, or the other issues. I gave it full permission and it installed the sdk and other everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to android sdk 23 AND the sdk of your choice (ie 25). I would recommend using the installer instead of the cmd install line as it is a lot easier to use, which can be found [here](https://www.nativescript.org/docs/default-source/default-document-library/nativescript-cli-setup-wix.exe). If you use the installer, it installs the versions you need and changes the environment variables for you as well as the other parts it needs.

EDIT

Another thing to mention is that even though the installer changes the paths for you and installs the sdks, you still need to make your own emulator image. It's not hard to setup but unfortunately the nativescript installer doesnt do that for you

Comment: if you downloaded the installer and ran it, you will have the android studio on your pc and you will have nativescript. The only possibility is that it didnt install correctly somehow. Did you try relaunching the installer?

Comment: So, far your option seems to have work. In that I mean, I see the "no issues detected" message when running "tns doctor" but the emulators aren't installed. When I run a sample app, it asks me to connect my device instead of showing me the emulator... do you know why this is?

Comment: if you havent configured an emulator, it wont be able to start one. unfortunately that is the one hing that isnt made for you

Comment: Can I add that to your answer? I don't think nativescript and android studio SDK actually can communicate. I installed emulator via the android studio and I don't see it working for nativescript

Comment: ill add it in with a bit of extra info

Answer (score 0):

First up, install Android Studio
https://developer.android.com/studio

Install android API level 25 (Nougat), from the SDK Manager.

Also, setup a virtual device, if you want to run apps on emulator.

That should setup all necessary environment variables for building Android apps with nativescript.

Comment: This is basically what I had done, before asking this questions

Answer (score 0):

According to the result of `tns doctor`, you have to install Android SDK.

1. You can simply install [Andriod Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio). Start up  Android studio, and use the built-in SDK manager to install required SDK, choose the correct version(>=23 <= 26) which was indicated in the result of `tns doctor`.
2. Alternatively, you can install Android SDK standalone, download it from Android developer site and extract files in your system, then follow the instruction of `tns doctor`, go to Android SDK folder, and find `sdkmanager`, and start up it to install required SDK with correct version.
3. Set `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable, the location points to the Android SDK folder, eg. E:\Users\hantsy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
4. Finally, try to run `tns doctor` again to check if all conditions are satisfied.

You can run the packaged Android app in one of the following:

1. Android SDK built-in simulator
2. A real Android mobile device
3. [Genymotion Android simulator](https://www.genymotion.com/), more productive than SDK built-in one

Comment: I get the same error. Are you sure the enviroment variable has to point to that dir?

Comment: @hidar  it is my android sdk location, in ur system, it should be different, you have to change it to yours.

Comment: he also need to install sdk 23, without it, nativescript wont build/run

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I have explained it in step 1 or step 2, did it confuse you ?

Comment: it didnt confuse me, you didnt explain fully/correctly. nativescript requires sdk 23 to be installed no matter what version you wish to target